# AWS Cognito Custom Authentication Flow - challengeResult is true before any authentication attempts

Tags: swift, authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

**Short Version**

Upon sign-in, Cognito triggers my `defineAuthChallenge` lambda function with an `event.session` that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    challengeName: 'SRP_A',
    challengeResult: true,
    challengeMetadata: null
  }
]
```

Why is `challengeResult` == `true` in `session[0]`, if no authentication attempts have been made? The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-define-auth-challenge.html#:%7E:text=be%20issued%20tokens.-,challengeResult,if%20the%20user%20successfully%20completed%20the%20challenge%2C%20or%20false%20otherwise.,-challengeMetadata) imply that the `challengeResult` value should be `false` if no auth attempts have been made. I should note that I can verify w/ CloudWatch that my definAuthChallenge lambda function is only being called once.

**Detailed Version**

I am trying to implement Passwordless Phone Number Authentication using AWS Amplify & Cognito in my iOS app; [like so](https://techinscribed.com/passwordless-phone-number-authentication-using-aws-amplify-cognito/). On my user enrollment page, I am invoking `Amplify.Auth.signUp` and `Amplify.Auth.signIn` like so:

```
    static func signUp(_ phone: String) {
        Amplify.Auth.signUp(username: phone, password: "uuidString12#") { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let signUpResult):
                if case let .confirmUser(deliveryDetails, _) = signUpResult.nextStep {
                    print("Delivery details \(String(describing: deliveryDetails))")
                } else {
                    print("Signup Complete")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("An error occurred while registering a user \(error)")
            }
        }
        Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: phone, password: "uuidString12#") { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                print("successful signIn")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("An error occurred while signing in a user \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

The `Amplify.Auth.signUp` action is successful, but `Amplify.Auth.signIn` is returning this error (in Xcode):

```
AuthError: Cannot issue tokens when ChallengeName is SRP_A
```

I have my Cognito User Pool configured with a preSignUp trigger and a defineAuthChallenge trigger with the following code, respectively:

preSignUp:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
    event.response.autoVerifyPhone = true;
    return event;
};
```

defineAuthChallenge:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.request.session);

    
    // If user is not registered
    if (event.request.userNotFound) {
        console.log("Checkpoint1");
        event.response.issueTokens = false;
        event.response.failAuthentication = true;
        throw new Error("User does not exist");
    }
    
    if (event.request.session.length >= 3 && event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeResult === false) { // wrong OTP even After 3 sessions?
        console.log("Checkpoint2");
        event.response.issueTokens = false;
        event.response.failAuthentication = true;
        throw new Error("Invalid OTP");
        
    } else if (event.request.session.length > 0 && event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeResult === true) { // Correct OTP!
        console.log("Checkpoint3");
        event.response.issueTokens = true;
        console.log("Checkpoint4");
        event.response.failAuthentication = false;
        console.log("Checkpoint5");
        
    } else { // not yet received correct OTP
        console.log("not yet received correct OTP");
        event.response.issueTokens = false;
        event.response.failAuthentication = false;
        event.response.challengeName = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE';
    }
    
    return event;
};
```

I have createAuthChallenge and verifyAuthChallenge functions defined as well but neither of those are being called as the auth flow is failing at defineAuthChallenge.

What seems to be happening is:

1. preSignUp lambda is triggered when the `Amplify.Auth.signUp` call is invoked
2. `Amplify.Auth.signUp` is successful when preSignUp lambda returns successfully
3. defineAuthChallenge is triggered by `Amplify.Auth.signIn` invocation
4. because `challengeResult` is `true` the first `else if` block in my defineAuthChallenge lambda is being executed (instead of the last `else` block) which attempts to set the `issueTokens` property to `true` but fails because the `challengeName` property is not being set to `'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE'` first.

So my question:
Why is `challengeResult` == `true` in `session[0]`, if no authentication attempts have been made? The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-define-auth-challenge.html#:%7E:text=be%20issued%20tokens.-,challengeResult,if%20the%20user%20successfully%20completed%20the%20challenge%2C%20or%20false%20otherwise.,-challengeMetadata) imply that the `challengeResult` value should be `false` if no auth attempts have been made.

Comment: ostrich  were you ever able to figure out why is challengeResult: true on the initial session request?  It is counterintuitive.

Comment: Any chance you have got this figured out?